# ReportBuilder + cxGrid = Error: "canvas does not allow drawing"

Tags: delphi, devexpress, reportbuilder, tcxgrid

Is there a **cxGrid** and a **ReportBuilder** report, linked to the same **DataSource**.
When I am printing the report, it show error: ***"canvas does not allow drawing"***.

This is my code to solve.

```
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  cxGridModeloDBTableView1.DataController.DataSource := nil;
  try
    pprReportBuilder.Print;
  finally
    cxGridModeloDBTableView1.DataController.DataSource := dsModeloView;
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  end;
```

Anyone can help me to solve this problem by another way?
Thanks!

Comment: After line 2 it is no longer linked to data source...

Comment: @user539484 OK, but I am looking for another solution.

Comment: ah, got it. So report printing fails while datasource link remains in effect, right?

Comment: Yes, the report fails if DataSouse is linked

Comment: My guess is that ReportBuilder is navigating the dataset to create the report, but the cxGrid does not expect that. Try using `cxGrid.BeginUpdate` and `cxGrid.EndUpdate` before and after `pprReportBuilder.Print`

Comment: @GuillemVicens I tried your idea now and it works! Thanks

Comment: glad to hear that. I'll post it as an answer just in case someone has the same problem. Feel free to accept it if you want :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that ReportBuilder is navigating the dataset to create the report, but the cxGrid does not expect that.

Instead of decoupling the datasource, try using `cxGrid.BeginUpdate` and `cxGrid.EndUpdate`before and after `pprReportBuilder.Print` like this:

```
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  cxGridModeloDBTableView1.BeginUpdate;
  try
    pprReportBuilder.Print;
  finally
    cxGridModeloDBTableView1.EndUpdate;
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  end;
```

HTH